# Recurrence sequences

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

So i got a recurrence sequence of $$a_n=2a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}-8a_{n-3}$$
With                    $$b_n=a_n-2a_{n-1}$$
I was able to show that      $$b_n=A2^n+B(-2)^n$$
Was the general solution for the sequence $b_n$.

Now I need to use induction on k to prove that

$$a_n=kA2^n+B(-2)^{n-1} ((-1)^k-1)+2^k a_{n-k}\tag 1$$      for $k\ge 1$
And deduce that
$$a_n=nA2^n-B2^{n-1}-B(-2)^{n-1}+2^n a_0$$

No matter how i shifted the numbers and indicied i cant get my inductive step to work. Also confused about the deduce part, Does the sequence b play a part in this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: Are you required to use induction? I don't know why $b_n$ is needed here. Just solve the characteristic equation for $a_n$ directly, you got a root of $-2$ and two $+2$'s so just apply the standard method.

Comment: BTW please use curly braces for exponents and subscripts, instead of parentheses.

Comment: yes induction is needed

Comment: Then you just replace $a_{n-k}$ in $(1)$ with $b_{n-k}+2a_{n-k-1}$ when you go from the case $k$ to $k+1$.

Comment: hey did that still and tried multiple variations still not getting any outcomes ):

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

We want to prove $a_n=kA2^n+B(-2)^{n-1} ((-1)^k-1)+2^k a_{n-k}\tag 1$

When $k=1$ it's true. If it's true for $k$, we have

$$a_n=kA2^n+B(-2)^{n-1} ((-1)^k-1)+2^k a_{n-k} \\
=kA2^n+B(-2)^{n-1} ((-1)^k-1)+2^k (b_{n-k}+2a_{n-k-1}) \\
=kA2^n+B(-2)^{n-1} ((-1)^k-1)+2^k (A2^{n-k}+B(-2)^{n-k}+2a_{n-k-1})\\
=kA2^n+A2^n+B(-2)^{n-1}((-1)^k-1-2(-1)^k)+2^{k+1}a_{n-k-1}\\
=(k+1)A2^n+B(-2)^{n-1}((-1)^{k+1}-1)+2^{k+1}a_{n-k-1}
$$

Note that $(-1)^k-1-2(-1)^k=(1-2)(-1)^k-1=(-1)^{k+1}-1$.